# How do I change the language on PlasticSCM MacOS

Tags: plasticscm

I got PlasticSCM with Unity but the language for the UI is Chinese. I cant seem to find a solution for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to enforce English. To do this:

1. Close Plastic SCM
2. Open the client.conf file (C:/users/user/appdata/local/.plastic4 on windows and User/.plastic4 on Mac) and set Language parameter to "force-en"